# Create a single legend for multiple kde plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I am making a graph in **python** and I would like it to have a single legend for all subplots. I am having problems as in my plot I cannot use **get_legend_handles_labels()** as it gives me problems to get my goal.

I am attaching the code and image to see if you could help me.

Thank you.

```
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, sharex=True, figsize=(16,4))
    
    sns.set(style="darkgrid")
    df = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full, '': 'original data'}),
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full_c, '': 'modified_data'})
    ])
    df1 = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full_c, '': 'original data'}),
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full_c, '': 'modified_data'})
    ])
    sns.kdeplot(ax=axes[0], data=df, x='FYA', hue='', fill=True, palette=['skyblue','lightcoral'], legend=False).set(title='black<-->white') 
    g, = sns.kdeplot(ax=axes[3], data=df1, x='FYA', hue='', fill=True, palette=['skyblue','lightcoral'], legend=True).set(title='asian<-->white')
    plt.setp(axes[3], ylabel='')

    handles, labels = axes.get_legend_handles_labels()
    figure.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right', ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(.75, 0.98))   

    #plt.setp(axes[-1, :], xlabel='FYA')
    #plt.setp(axes[:, 0], ylabel='Density')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot) function, the subplots can be created in one go.  As input, a combined dataframe is needed, concatenating the separate dataframes. The `col=` keyword indicates which dataframe column will start a new subplot. You might need to check the [`kdeplot` documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) for additional keywords (such as `common_norm=` and `multiple=`).

Note that `displot` is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) which creates its own figure, and sets the `figsize` depending on the number of subplots, and the `height=` and `aspect=` keywords.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
df = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(20), '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(15), '': 'modified_data'})])
df1 = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(22), '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(25), '': 'modified_data'})])
df2 = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(21), '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(28), '': 'modified_data'})])
df3 = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(29), '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': np.random.randn(17), '': 'modified_data'})])

combined_df = pd.concat({'black<->orange': df, 'red<->yellow': df1, 'green<->blue': df2, 'purple<->pink': df3})
combined_df = combined_df.reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'subplot'}).reset_index()

g = sns.displot(kind='kde', data=combined_df, x='FYA', hue='', fill=True, col='subplot')
for ax, col_name in zip(g.axes.flat, g.col_names):
    ax.set_title(col_name)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot with kde]

PS: If, for some reason, you prefer to stay closer to the original code,  you can use `sns.movelegend()`. This is new in Seaborn 0.11.2 and changes the position and other legend properties. Note that in matplotlib a legend belongs to a subplot (`ax`), not with the surrounding figure. Due to the complexity of seaborn plots, often matplotlib's standard legend mechanism can't be used, and a custom legend needs to be created.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

preds_full = np.random.randn(20, 20).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()
preds_full_c = np.random.randn(20, 15).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()

figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(16, 4))

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
df = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full, '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full_c, '': 'modified_data'})])
df1 = pd.concat(axis=0, ignore_index=True, objs=[
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full, '': 'original data'}),
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FYA': preds_full_c, '': 'modified_data'})])
sns.kdeplot(ax=axes[0], data=df, x='FYA', hue='', fill=True, palette=['skyblue', 'lightcoral'], legend=False)
axes[0].set(title='black<-->white')
sns.kdeplot(ax=axes[3], data=df1, x='FYA', hue='', fill=True, palette=['skyblue', 'lightcoral'], legend=True)
axes[3].set(title='asian<-->white')
sns.move_legend(axes[3], loc='lower right', ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.08))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: moving a seaborn legend]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Regarding the first solution you have given. How could I remove the title 'subplot=' from each subplot ? And how could I concatenate an equivalent row below the existing one ?

Best regards.

Comment: I updated the example, adding a loop to change the subplot titles. If you just want to have the same type of data in more rows, you can use `col_wrap=4`.